# Do Google Compute instances have a stable public DNS name?

Tags: google-compute-engine

This is a question in two parts:

- Do GCE instances have a stable public DNS name? The default DNS name for instance with public IP a.b.c.d seems to be d.c.b.a.bc.googleusercontent.com
- If yes, what's the best way to obtain this information? Here's the hack I've been using thus far:

  ```
  EXTERNAL_IP=$(curl -s http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/)
  EXTERNAL_DNS=$(dig +short -x ${EXTERNAL_IP})
  ```

Comment: The d.c.b.a.bc.googleusercontent.com DNS names are effectively IP addresses. Can you share why you're looking for the DNS name instead of IP address?

Comment: @BrianDorsey some applications (e.g. Puppet) need DNS names and don't work well with IP addresses.

Comment: For ssh access during development it would be easier to remember and type names (matching the project instance name) rather than IP addresses, without needing to set up separate dyndns.

Answer (score 1):

reverse lookup is okay to do, for IP address you would probably prefer using gcutil
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/tips

EXTERNAL_IP=$(gcutil getinstance --format=csv --zone=[your_zone] [your_instance]  | grep external-ip | cut -d "," -f 2)

Comment: Well ideally I wouldn't even have to do a reverse lookup -- the public DNS name would just be part of the instance metadata. For instance, on EC2 you can GET http://.../latest/meta-data/public-hostname

Answer (score 0):

GCE instances don't currently have a public DNS name for their external IP address. But there is now a `gcloud compute config-ssh` ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh)) command that's a pretty good substitute.

This will insert `Host` blocks into your `~/.ssh/config` file that contain the IP address and configuration for the host key.

Although this only helps with SSH (and SSH-based applications like Mosh and git+ssh), it does have a few advantages over DNS:

- There is no caching/propagation delay as you might have with DNS
- It pre-populates the right host key, and the host key is checked the right way even if the ephemeral IP address changes.

Example:

```
$ gcloud compute config-ssh
...
$ ssh myhost.us-west1-b.surly-koala-232
```