# Force kafka to connect brokers through IPs, not via hostnames

Tags: apache-kafka, ssh-tunnel, kcat

We have following kafka-ssh-tunneling setup.

`ssh -N $JUMPHOST -L 2181:w.x.y.z:2181 -L 9092:a.b.c.d:9092 -L 9091:e.e.f.f:9092`

- broker IP is **a.b.c.d** , There is local lo0 device alias with same IP address
- zookeper IP is **w.x.y.z** , There is local device alias  with same IP address
- kafkahost "entry" host is **e.e.f.f**

Our planned use case is `kafkacat -C -b localhost:9091 -t <topic>`

**Problem:**
Connecting to kafka host/ zookepers works fine, however
kafka clients ( e.g. kafkacat ) are accessing brokers by their hostname, `ip-a.b.c.d.eu-central-1.compute.internal` , not by their IP's.

To counteract, I've added entry to /etc/hosts

`a.b.c.d      ip-a.b.c.d.eu-central-1.compute.internal`

Still doesn't work,
although pinging to that hostname is successful.

Nslookup gives

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ip-a.b.c.d.eu-central-1.compute.internal
Address: a.b.c.d
** server can't find ip-a.b.c.d.eu-central-1.compute.internal: NXDOMAIN
```

**Question:**
Is there a way telling kafka to connect brokers through IP's and not via hostnames?
If not, will starting local dns server might resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

What is happening here is:

1. The broker receives a petition from the client and returns him `ip-a.b.c.d.eu-central-1.compute.internal`, as this is the host name of the broker and **the default value for listeners.** (*this is the key*)
2. Your client tries to send data to the broker using the metadata it was given. But as it can't resolve `ip-a.b.c.d.eu-central-1.compute.internal`, it fails without even reaching the cluster, caused by a networking issue out of Kafka's scope.

   If you set the value on `/etc/hosts`, you will fix the address resolution problem; The client will now be able to reach the cluster, solving the previous networking issue.

   The following step involves Kafka replying with the **`448_in_your_face`** error code (*the exact code name may differ*). Your petition fails again, now on cluster-side: your client is asking for a broker *called/referenced* `a.b.c.d`, but **there is no registered listener with that name**, as its identifier is still                     `ip-a.b.c.d.eu-central-1.compute.internal`.

---

The key here is within the **`advertised.listeners`** property, located in the `server.properties` configuration file.
In order your clients to be able to connect, modify that property, directly setting the ip there, or a resolvable dns (*using IP for this example*):

**`advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://a.b.c.d:9092`**

Now on client side, just use the IP in order to connect with the broker:

`bootstrap.servers = a.b.c.d:9092`

When the petition from the client is received, kafka will recognize the content of  `bootstrap.servers` as one of its registered listeners, hence accepting the connection.

Comment: Thanks for dig-in to my complex problem. I will ask our devOps team to see if they can change it, however I've found another work-around as solution, I will post it as just in case someone will need it.

Comment: See this answer here for more on how advertised.listeners works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44443308/2188893

Answer (score 1):

Found workaround. Posting here If anyone might face my problem.

**Steps are following:**

- Create dummy aliases for all host you are planning to use, `sudo ip add a dev lo $ip`
- These aliases should **NOT** have the same broker/zookeper IPs, **BUT** 127.0.j.k format
- Add `ip-<>.<>.<>.<>.eu-central-1.compute.internal` < -- > `127.0.[].[]` mapping to `/etc/hosts`
- Create tunnel via SSH, taking account relation of broker/zookeper's IPs and your local (aliased) IPs

`ssh -N $JUMPHOST -L 2181:<localIP>:<remoteIP>:2181 -L 9092:<localIP>:<remoteIP>:9092 ...`

then you can consume messages via
`kafkacat -C -b 127.0.[].[]:9092 -t <topic>`

Comment: Why not edit the `advertised.listeners` to return the IP addresses?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, that was mentioned before. I will ask our DevOps to see if they can do it, but usually they are very conservative to any changes : )

Comment: Otherwise, yeah, `compute.internal` DNS names would need to be mapped externally via an ELB, for example